# How to avoid the behavior of set htmlText in RichTextEditor?

Tags: apache-flex, behavior, rich-text-editor, htmltext

I'm having this problem of adding an image to the textArea in RichTextEditor (RTE) on the fly and this image seems to "reset" the html properties of the textArea.
Better explained:

The user starts writing something in the TextArea (with **Verdana in size:12** font settings). When he adds an image to the text area, the cursor right after the image gets very small and the font settings are reset to **HUM777B in size:2**.

How could I avoid this behavior?

It seems Flex adds additional HTML code before the image tag. If there was any way to avoid this I would be able to add my own settings to the tags.

Answer (score 0):

Just before you programmatically add the image to the textArea, create a variable and store a reference to the textArea styling info. Set the styling info using this variable after you have added the image.